# Send private message to a list of people

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

My bot is going to send a private message to a list of people who are accepted.
I want to type in a command that sends a message to everyone in the `.json` file.
I have tried with a loop, but can't get it to work.

I am thinking of this to be the json file:

```json
{
    "1": "Name#0001",
    "2": "Guy#0001",
    "3": "Person#0001"
}
```

This is my index.js or main.js:

```js
var ytLinks = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./ytvids.json', 'utf8'));

if (args[1] === 'send') {
  const userValues = Object.values(acceptedUsers);
  var userList = '';
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < userValues.length; i++) {
    userList += userValues[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### something.json:

```json
{
    "1": "Name#0001",
    "2": "Guy#0001",
    "3": "Person#0001"
}
```

#### index.js:

```js
const obj = require('./something.json') // require object from file

// execute function on each entry (user tag)
Object.values(obj).forEach((tag) => {

    // find each user via tag and send DM 
    client.users.cache.find(user => user.tag === tag).send('This is a DM') 
});
```

---

- [`Object.values()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Array.prototype.find()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

---

Be careful, too much mass DMing can lead to problems with Discord's Terms of Service

Comment: In a performace perspective, Array.forEach is considerably slower than for...of and Array.map, so you should probably switch that to a for...of loop.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `Array#forEach()` is definitely not slower than `Array#map()`

Comment: Furthermore, although `for...of` is considered faster, it only makes a difference when iterating over upwards of millions of elements. Otherwise, it doesn't matter.